# understanding how to define pullback of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given two manifolds $M, N$ and two open sets $ U \subset M, V\subset N$ and assume that the local coordinates are around $V$ are $v_1, v_2, v_3, ...v_n$ then we have the following map

$$U \to V \to R^m$$ and we have the coordinate chart $ \phi \circ f:U \to R^m$ and so the local coordinates here can be defined to be $\pi_i(\phi \circ f)=(\pi_i\circ \phi )\circ f=v_i\circ f$ and now given any differential form

$\omega=g dv_{i_1}dv_{i_2} \dots dv_{i_n}$ we can pull it back to $f*(\omega)=g \circ f d(v_{i_1}\circ f)d(v_{i_1}\circ f)\dots d(v_{i_n}\circ f)$.

Is it correct? One step I cannot understand is why $\phi \circ f$ will be a coordinate chart map because $f$ need not be a homeomorphim.  Its just a smooth map and nothing else.

Comment: $\phi\circ f$ need not be a chart, this equality follows from the fact that $f^*$ is a ring homomorphism from $\Omega^*(N):=\bigoplus_{i} \Omega^i(N) \to \Omega^*(M) $ (verify this!)

Comment: okay, then how do I get an idea about local coordinates of $U$ and what would be the pullback? I am not able to understand.

Comment: The equation you wrote is correct, you could still write out a coordinate chart on $U$ and express $f^*\omega$ in terms of it, but it is not required.

Comment: Do you mean any coordinate chart on $U$ or a coordinate chart defined using the coordinate chart of $V$?

Comment: Since $f^*\omega$ is a form on $M$, it can always be locally expressed in terms of the basis one forms $dx^1, \cdots dx^m$ which are defined on an open neighborhood $U\subset M$.

Comment: but we do not know that $f^*\omega$ is a form unless we define it. And to define it I need to understand about the local coordinates first.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$I always prefer to break this down into two parts, one is pure linear algebra and the other is differentiation.

The first thing to do is to understand the pullback of a linear map $L: X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces. Let $X^*$ and $Y^*$ be the dual vector spaces of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Any element $\ell \in X^*$ is a linear function $\ell: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The pullback of $L$ is the linear map $$ L^*: Y^* \rightarrow X^*,$$ where if $\mu \in Y^*$, the, by definition, $\mu$ is a linear function $\mu: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $L^*\mu \in X^*$ is the linear function
$$ (L^*\mu)(x) = \mu(L(x)). $$
If you're unfamiliar with this, I recommend spending some time studying this.

Recall that any $\omega \in \Lambda^kX^*$ is an alternating multilinear function of $k$ vectors.
The pullback of an exterior tensor $\omega \in \Lambda^kY^*$ by the linear map $L: X \rightarrow Y$ is defined to be the exterior tensor $L^*\omega \in \Lambda^kX^*$, where if $x_1, \dots, x_k \in X$, then
$$ L^*\omega(x_1, \dots, x_k) = \omega(L(x_1), \dots, L(x_k)). $$

After this, you can define pullback of differential forms as follows. Given a smooth map $f: M \rightarrow N$ (need not be a diffeomorphism), the pullback of a zero form (i.e., a function) $\phi: N \rightarrow \R$ is simply
$$ f^*\phi = \phi\circ f. $$
Next, recall that the differential (Jacobian) of $f: M \rightarrow N$ defines, for each $x \in M$, a linear map
$$ \partial f(x): T_xM \rightarrow T_{f(x)}N, $$
where if $v \in M$, then
$$ (\partial f(x))(v) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(c(t)), $$
where $c$ is a curve such that $c(0) = x$ and $c'(0) = v$.

Then given any differential $k$-form $\omega$ on an open subset of $M$, its pullback by $f$ is simply the differential form $f^*\omega$, given by
$$ (f^*\omega)(x) = (\partial f(x))^*(\omega(f(x))),
$$
where the rightside is the linear algebraic pullback described in the first few paragraphs.

If $M$ or $N$ is an open subset of $\R^n$, then you can can write everything with respect to the coordinates $(x^1, \cdots, x^n)$, the standard basis $(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)$, the dual basis $(dx^1, \dots, d^n)$ (which can also be viewed as differentials of the functions $x^i: \R^n \rightarrow \R$). This will lead you to the correct formulas you are looking for.

This is obvious a circuitous route, but I believe it shows more clearly how everything fits together naturally.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of back and forth in the comments I have decided to write an extended discussion here.

The coordinate free way to describe the pull back of forms is to think of it as the dual to the differential.

If $f: M\to N$ is a smooth map, $\omega\in \Omega^k(N)$ and $w_1,\cdots, w_k\in T_pM$ we define $$f^*\omega_p(w_1,\cdots, w_k):=\omega_{f(p)}(T_pf\cdot w_1,T_pf\cdot w_2,\cdots,T_pf\cdot w_k)$$ It's clear that this defines a section $f^*\omega: M\to \bigwedge^kT^*M$ (the resulting form is alternating and gives an element of $\bigwedge^k T_p^*M$ at each $p\in M$), but one must confirm that it is smooth.

Note that on $\Omega^0(N):=C^\infty(M)$, $f^*g:= (g\circ f)$.

We can extend this to a map $f^*:\Omega^*(N)\to \Omega^*(M)$ (these spaces are formal sums of forms) by extending the maps on each $\Omega^k$. We will now verify that $f^*$ is a ring homomorphism with the product structure given by $\wedge$.

Take $\omega\in\Omega^k(N), \eta\in \Omega^j(N)$ and $w_1,\cdots, w_{k+j}\in T_pM$. We have \begin{align}f^*(\omega\wedge\eta)(w_1,\cdots, w_{k+j}):&= \sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+j}} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\omega(T_pf\cdot w_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, T_pf\cdot w_{\sigma(k)})\eta( T_pf\cdot w_{\sigma(k+1)},\cdots, T_pf\cdot w_{\sigma(k+j)})\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+j}} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)f^*\omega(w_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, w_{\sigma(k)})f^*\eta(w_{\sigma(k+1)},\cdots, w_{\sigma(j+k)})\\
&=(f^*\omega)\wedge(f^*\eta)(w_1,\cdots, w_{k+j})\end{align}
This tells us that $f^*$ commutes with $\wedge$ and hence defines a ring homomorphism $\Omega^*(N)\to \Omega^*(M)$

We can now see that in local coordinates, if we have a form $\omega=\sum_{i_1,\cdots, i_k} \omega_{i_1i_1\cdots i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_k}$ we can say $$f^*\omega=\sum_{i_1,\cdots, i_k}(\omega_{i_1i_2\cdots i_k}\circ f)(f^*dx^{i_1})\wedge(f^* dx^{i_2})\wedge\cdots\wedge(f^* dx^{i_k})$$

In order to obtain the final equality, we must investigate what $f^*dx^j$ looks like. If $v\in T_pM$ we have $f^*dx^j(v):= dx^j(T_pf\cdot v)$. If $\gamma: (-1, 1)\to M$ is a curve with $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}\gamma=v$ we have \begin{align}dx^j(T_pf\cdot v):&=dx^j([f\circ \gamma])\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}(x^j(f\circ \gamma(t)))\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}(x^j\circ f)(\gamma(t))\\
&=d(x^j\circ f)(v)\end{align}
(This proof works for any function $g$ in place of $x^j$, $f^*dg=d(f^*g)$) and we conclude that $$f^*\omega=\sum_{i_1\cdots i_k}(\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}\circ f)(d(x^{i_1}\circ f))\wedge(d(x^{i_2}\circ f))\wedge\cdots\wedge(d(x^{i_k}\circ f))$$ as desired.

Now, we may inspect more closely the properties of $d(x^j\circ f)$. If $f:M\to N$ takes in local coordinates $f(y^1, \cdots, y^{m})=(f^1(y^1,\cdots, y^m),\cdots, f^n(y^1,\cdots, y^m))$ where $y^i$ are the local coordinates on $m$ we see that $x^i\circ f(y^1, \cdots, y^m)=f^i(y^1, \cdots, y^m)$ so $d(x^i\circ f)=\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^{j}}(y^1,\cdots, y^m)dy^j$ and we find that $$f^*\omega=\sum_{i_1\cdots i_k}\bigg(f^*\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}\bigg(\sum_{j_1} \frac{\partial f^{i_1}}{\partial y^{j_1}} dy^{j_1}\bigg)\wedge\bigg(\sum_{j_2} \frac{\partial f^{i_2}}{\partial y^{j_2}} dy^{j_2}\bigg)\wedge\cdots\wedge\bigg(\sum_{j_k} \frac{\partial f^{i_k}}{\partial y^{j_k}} dy^{j_k}\bigg)\bigg)$$